# How to set taskbar progress bar in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

Does anyone know if its possible to set the progress bar in a UWP?

[image]

Perhaps its possible with project Centennial?

Mike

Comment: With project cenntenial you can convert classic windows app to UWP app. In classic app you can create progress bar.

Comment: Yep I thought as much. So there is no way to do it with standard UWP tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it now, but you can [vote](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9850857-add-a-windows-api-to-show-progress-on-the-taskbar) for this feature to be added in future Windows 10 builds

Comment: link is dead: "This UserVoice instance is no longer available", "Account has been deleted"

Comment: Seems that wpdev.uservoice.com is no longer available at all. Now all proposals could be submitted to developercommunity.visualstudio.com (suggest a feature)